# Making sure a webpage looks the same when resized

Tags: css, xhtml, web-standards

I couldn't find a previous post for this, and I apologize if this is an uber-n00b question.

I am working on my first practice site (just XHTML and CSS/3 stages right now).  I wanted to test the page to make sure that when I reduce the size of the browser window everything still looks the same.  When I did that, my navigation column overlapped part of the page and the background image I have embedded in my h1 header doesn't fill all the x-axis all the way to the right.

What did I do wrong, and how can I fix this the right (web standards)?

P.S...Here's the code

```
h1 { 
  font-size: x-large; 
  color: white; 
  padding-top: 2em; 
  padding-bottom: .2em; 
  padding-left: .4em; 
  margin: 0; 
  background: navy url(backgrounds/header-bg.jpg) repeat-y right; 
} 

#navigation { 
  width: 180px; 
  height: 484px; 
  background: #7da5d8 url(backgrounds/nav-bg.jpg) no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code in question, lots of different things could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several strategies.  it's really an art and it's a bit too involved to be answered fully here.  It's something web designers have been dealing with for years, and you'll develop your own style and strategy, but there are good recommendations and best practices available on the web to find.

I'd start with this search:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=web+design+gracefully++resize&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC

This is the first truly good result from that search:  http://mirificampress.com/permalink/daynamically_resizing_text_with_css_and_javascript

but there are other good results as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a fixed width to the main container or the body itself.

```
body{
    width:1000px;
}
```

If you post your current code, we may give you a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

*Ah well, this was going to be a comment, but I just kept going...*

The nav column overlap is most likely because it is defined with a fixed width (px or em (which are fixed for this purpose)) and not a fluid unit like percentage.  With all respect to David Stratton (and he's right, it is an art to in-depth to be answered here), try building your layout using percentages when appropriate to make the page scale well.

In response to the idea of fixing the width of an outer container, that is also a possibility, but one which doesn't degrade nicely if the user has a *very* small or large screen or a *very* high or low resolution.

Try googling with fluid page layout web design